# To be seen in something

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrasal-verbs

What does this phrase mean? Is it a phrasal verb?

> Saturn *is seen* in Leo.

Comment: IMO, Saturn in Leo is an astrological term, from which I think the meaning of the phrase you asked can be extrapolated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Saturn is seen in Leo.

means "The planet Saturn is visible within the boundaries of the constellation Leo." This construction is used both in astrology, and in naked-eye or small-telescope (amateur) astronomy. I have seen and used it many times in the latter context.  As the answer by James K correctly said, it is not a phrasal verb, and is in the passive voice, which is common for this expression. But a variant can be used in the active voice, as with:

> - You can see Saturn in Leo starting next Tuesday.
> - I had seen Saturn in Leo very clearly with my new telescope.

Answer (score 3):

That is not a phrasal verb.

It is a passive construction. "be + past-particple".  "Seen" is the past particple of "see".

It means  "One sees Saturn in Leo", (Here "one" is the pronoun, meaning "someone")
With a sentence like this, it is natural to use the passive, since the identity of the subject isn't known and isn't important.